# How do I properly loop through two nested json structures in golang

Tags: json, loops, go, nested

I am new to Go. I have 2 identical json nested structures that are each populated with the output of 2 api calls. One call fetches cpu and the other memory metrics. I can unmarshal each of them individually and print out the project name and values of cpu and memory, albeit in 2 separate code blocks.  The problem I am having is that I would like to print out both cpu and memory metrics on the same line, next to their project name.

Here is the code I am using to print out the CPU metrics by Project. It creates a nice CSV formatted output:

```
// CPU Metrics
// Loop through the data for the Month, Project, CPU requests, and CPU Usage
   fmt.Println("Month, Project, CPU Request(Core hours), CPU Usage(Core hours)\n")
   for _, value_cpu := range rh_values_cpu.Data {
       for _, val_cpu := range value_cpu.Projects {
        str := val_cpu.Project
        s := strings.Contains(str, "openshift")
         if s == true  {
            continue
        }
           fmt.Printf("%s, %s, ", value_cpu.Date, val_cpu.Project)
           for _, v_cpu := range val_cpu.Values {
           fmt.Printf("%.1f, %.1f\n", v_cpu.Request.Value, v_cpu.Usage.Value)
         }
       }
    }
```

I have similar code for the memory metrics which also works fine.

Here is the code I am using to loop through the two json structures. I suspect that I'm not using the nested loops properly or need to solve the problem differently.

```
// CPU & Memory Metrics
// Loop through the data for the Month, Project, CPU requests, CPU Usage, Memory requests, and Memory Usage
   fmt.Println("Month, Project, CPU Request(Core hours), CPU Usage(Core hours) Memory Request(mBytes), Memory Usage(mBytes)\n")
   for _, value_cpu := range rh_values_cpu.Data {
    for _, value_mem := range rh_values_MEM.Data {
      for _, val_cpu := range value_cpu.Projects {
        for _, val_mem := range value_mem.Projects {
         str := val_cpu.Project
         s := strings.Contains(str, "openshift")
          if s == true  {
            continue
        }
           fmt.Printf("%s, %s, ", value_cpu.Date, val_cpu.Project)
           for _, v_cpu := range val_cpu.Values {
              fmt.Printf("%.1f, %.1f ", v_cpu.Request.Value, v_cpu.Usage.Value)
                for _,v_mem := range val_mem.Values {
                  fmt.Printf("%.1f, %.1f\n", v_mem.Request.Value, v_mem.Usage.Value)
       }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

And here is of one the json structures:

```
type RH_Output_MEM struct {
    Meta struct {
        Count    int    `json:"count"`
        Others   int    `json:"others"`
        Currency string `json:"currency"`
        Filter   struct {
            Resolution     string `json:"resolution"`
            TimeScopeValue string `json:"time_scope_value"`
            TimeScopeUnits string `json:"time_scope_units"`
            Limit          int    `json:"limit"`
            Offset         int    `json:"offset"`
        } `json:"filter"`
        GroupBy struct {
            Project []string `json:"project"`
        } `json:"group_by"`
        OrderBy struct {
        } `json:"order_by"`
        Exclude struct {
        } `json:"exclude"`
        Total struct {
            Usage struct {
                Value float64 `json:"value"`
                Units string  `json:"units"`
            } `json:"usage"`
            Request struct {
                Value float64 `json:"value"`
                Units string  `json:"units"`
            } `json:"request"`
            Limit struct {
                Value float64 `json:"value"`
                Units string  `json:"units"`
            } `json:"limit"`
            Capacity struct {
                Value float64 `json:"value"`
                Units string  `json:"units"`
            } `json:"capacity"`
            Infrastructure struct {
                Raw struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"raw"`
                Markup struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"markup"`
                Usage struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"usage"`
                Distributed struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"distributed"`
                Total struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"total"`
            } `json:"infrastructure"`
            Supplementary struct {
                Raw struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"raw"`
                Markup struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"markup"`
                Usage struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"usage"`
                Distributed struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"distributed"`
                Total struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"total"`
            } `json:"supplementary"`
            Cost struct {
                Raw struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"raw"`
                Markup struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"markup"`
                Usage struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"usage"`
                Distributed struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"distributed"`
                Total struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"total"`
            } `json:"cost"`
        } `json:"total"`
    } `json:"meta"`
    Links struct {
        First    string      `json:"first"`
        Next     string      `json:"next"`
        Previous interface{} `json:"previous"`
        Last     string      `json:"last"`
    } `json:"links"`
    Data []struct {
        Date     string `json:"date"`
        Projects []struct {
            Project string `json:"project"`
            Values  []struct {
                Date    string `json:"date"`
                Project string `json:"project"`
                Usage   struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"usage"`
                Request struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"request"`
                Limit struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"limit"`
                Capacity struct {
                    Value float64 `json:"value"`
                    Units string  `json:"units"`
                } `json:"capacity"`
                Classification string   `json:"classification"`
                SourceUUID     []string `json:"source_uuid"`
                Clusters       []string `json:"clusters"`
                Infrastructure struct {
                    Raw struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"raw"`
                    Markup struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"markup"`
                    Usage struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"usage"`
                    Distributed struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"distributed"`
                    Total struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"total"`
                } `json:"infrastructure"`
                Supplementary struct {
                    Raw struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"raw"`
                    Markup struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"markup"`
                    Usage struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"usage"`
                    Distributed struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"distributed"`
                    Total struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"total"`
                } `json:"supplementary"`
                Cost struct {
                    Raw struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"raw"`
                    Markup struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"markup"`
                    Usage struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"usage"`
                    Distributed struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"distributed"`
                    Total struct {
                        Value float64 `json:"value"`
                        Units string  `json:"units"`
                    } `json:"total"`
                } `json:"cost"`
            } `json:"values"`
        } `json:"projects"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
```

And here is a snippet of the output I am getting when running the program. As you can see, the Date, Project, and inner loop (CPU metrics) repeats itself, while the outer loop (Memory metrics) runs:

I'm looking for an output where I have one line per project (Month, Project, CPU metrics, Memory metrics)

```
Month, Project, CPU Request(Core hours), CPU Usage(Core hours) Memory Request(mBytes), Memory Usage(mBytes)
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 4353.2
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 1115.6, 1081.4
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 10675.9
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 100.9, 284.0
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 70064.5
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 773088.9, 427757.8
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 9440.0, 11610.3
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 9471.3, 11696.9
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 2455.2
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 3.3
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 0.0, 0.0
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, -0.3, 0.0
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 3785.0, 6610.4
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 252.3, 1007.8
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 757.0, 883.0
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 1009.4, 1613.4
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 378.5, 413.5
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 908.4, 2856.8
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 252.3, 248.7
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 66873.8, 21035.3
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 353.3, 611.9
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 10203.6, 12418.3
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 504.7, 398.3
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 1135.5, 2248.5
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 252.3, 610.6
2022-12, amq-demo-streams, 0.0, 34.0, 252.3, 370.6
```

Comment: I have tried to use Append to merge the two slices together but no luck. Have also tried to reduce the code to more directly access elements in the slice. Nothing has worked and need some help - John

Comment: Could be nice to have the Metrics output loop.

Comment: Plus, you're not outputting in a CSV compatible way right now.

Comment: @tteixeira Do you mean the raw data used to run the for loops against ? I can't post it here because it contains proprietary information but I can supply a snippet from it.  Please let me know

Comment: @jmacioni, nope, I was referring to the "I have similar code for the memory metrics which also works fine." that you wrote. Although, my answer should cover your question, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allowed myself to use simpler struct definition. You can always adapt this code to your structs.

```golang
type Cpu struct {
    Project string
    Data    []Data
}

type Memory struct {
    Project string
    Data    []Data
}

type Data struct {
    Date     string
    Projects []Project
}

type Project struct {
    Project string
    Values  []struct {
        Request float64
        Value   float64
    }
}

func CSVOutput(cpu Cpu, mem Memory) error {
    // Returns an error if cpu & memory's data are the same length
    if len(cpu.Data) != len(mem.Data) {
        return fmt.Errorf("cpu.Data and mem.Data don't have the same length")
    }

    // Printing CSV file header
    fmt.Println("Month, Project, CPU Request(Core hours), CPU Usage(Core hours) Memory Request(mBytes), Memory Usage(mBytes)")
    for i := range cpu.Data {
        cpuData := cpu.Data[i]
        memData := mem.Data[i]

        // Using the format from Errorf to add context to the error
        if len(cpuData.Projects) != len(memData.Projects) {
            return fmt.Errorf("cpu.Data[%d].Projects and mem.Data[%d].Projects don't have the same length", i, i)
        }

        for j := range cpuData.Projects {
            cpuProject := cpuData.Projects[j]
            memProject := memData.Projects[j]

            if len(cpuProject.Values) != len(memProject.Values) {
                return fmt.Errorf("cpu.Data[%d].Projects[%d].Values and mem.Data[%d].Projects[%d].Values don't have the same length", i, j, i, j)
            }

            name := cpuProject.Project
            date := cpuData.Date

            // Continue if the cpu project concerns openshift
            if strings.Contains(name, "openshift") {
                continue
            }

            for k := range cpuProject.Values {
                cpuValue := cpuProject.Values[k]
                memValue := memProject.Values[k]

                fmt.Printf("%s, %s, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f", date, name, cpuValue.Request, cpuValue.Value, memValue.Request, memValue.Value)
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

This code only works if you receive as much cpu's data as memory's data.
If it isn't the case, you will have to find a way to link a certain cpu's data to its memory equivalent.
This issue can be furthermore discussed if you think the situation might show up.

Comment: Thank you so much. With a little adjustment this worked great !!